# Run validations in update action of CRUD with multiple models before update db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models - Dog and Bone. Dog has_one Bone, Bone belongs_to Dog. Dog has name, Bone has color and dogs_id.

In edit form user can change dog's name and bone's color.
I need to run dog's and bone's validations before update db. Here is my code:

```
def update
  @dog = Dog.find(params[:id])
  @bone = @dog.bone

  if @dog.update(dog_params) && @bone.update(bone_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

In this case, if dog is valid and bone isn't, it will save only dog's progress in db and then render edit again. But I don't want to change db before all of them are valid.

Comment: Can you show us your `dog_params` and `bone_params`?

Comment: @Pavan `dog_params` and `bone_params` are just hashes like {name: 'Sam'} and {color: 'red'}

Comment: May be you can use `accepets_nested_attributes_for :bone` and make `dog_params` as `params.require(:dog).permit(:name,bone_attribues: [:id,:color,:dog_id])` and so by calling just `if @dog.update(dog_params)` will make sure the params updated if they are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more feasible way is using **[accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)**.

```
#app/models/dog.rb
Class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :bone
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bone
#your validations

end
```

And the `update` method as

```
def update
  @dog = Dog.find(params[:id])

  if @dog.update(dog_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end 

private

def dog_params
  params.require(:dog).permit(:name,bone_attribues: [:id,:color,:dog_id])
end
```

This will make sure that the **`attributes(both parent and child)`** are updated if they are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `valid?` on each model

```
def update
  @dog = Dog.find(params[:id])
  @bone = @dog.bone

  @dog.assign_attributes dog_params
  @bone.assign_attributes bone_params

  if @dog.valid? && @bone.valid?
    @dog.save
    @bone.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about #assign_attributes.